# Caching "render json" in Rails without page caching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I have a controller method like this, which renders an object as JSON.

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render json: @my_object, serializer: MyCustomSerializer
    end
  end
end
```

Now the json generation takes at least 12 seconds, so I would like to cache this. I could use HTTP caching here (with a stale? check), but that would still require other clients (browsers) to hit the slow JSON rendering the very first time.

How can I cache this "render json" call?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using active model serializers, you can override `serializable_hash` on the serializer to return a cached version, using [`Rails.cache.fetch`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch), for example:

```
def serializable_hash
  Rails.cache.fetch(my_cache_key) { super }
end
```

Replace `my_cache_key` with a cache key that will invalidate the cached JSON (probably something based on `updated_at`).